# How to get predicted R-square from statmodels?

Tags: r-squared

How can I get predicted R-square along with R-square and Adj-Rsquare in statmodels?

code

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from statsmodels.stats import anova

mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("mtcars", "datasets", cache=True).data
df = pd.DataFrame(mtcars)
model = smf.ols(formula='mpg ~ wt', data=mtcars).fit()
model.summary()
```

output

[image]

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/eca90e41ee2bf4f9519e0e3e05edd7c0) is a Python gist obtaining $R^2$ and $R_{\text{adj}}$ in `statsmodels`. Not sure what you mean by "predicted R-square" vs "R-square" since $R^2$ uses the residuals...

Comment: @Galen You can find the description about predicated-squared (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242770/difference-between-adjusted-r-squared-and-predicted-r-squared).

Comment: Interesting. It looks like a sort of leave-one-out $R^2$. I have updated the Python gist to calculate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question [Difference between Adjusted R Squared and Predicted R Squared](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242770/difference-between-adjusted-r-squared-and-predicted-r-squared) gives a procedure as follows:

> - A data point from your dataset is removed
> - A refitted linear regression model is generated
> - The removed data point is plugged into the refitted linear model, generating a predicted value
> - The removed data point is placed back into your dataset. Repeat from step 1 for the next data point until all data points have had a chance to be removed.

Modifying your example, we can use the following:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.stats import anova
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut

# Data
mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("mtcars", "datasets", cache=True).data
y = mtcars.mpg.to_numpy()
X = sm.add_constant(mtcars.wt.to_numpy())

# Calculate PRESS and pre_rsq
loo_res = []
for train_index, test_index in LeaveOneOut().split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    model = sm.OLS(y_train, X_train)
    results = model.fit()
    loo_res.append(*(y_test - results.predict(X_test)))

pred_rsq = 1 - np.sum(np.square(loo_res)) / np.var(y) / y.size

# rsquared on all data
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit()


# Print results
print(results.rsquared, results.rsquared_adj, pred_rsq)
```